# How confifure ticket printer in ms access

Tags: ms-access, printing, vba

I have **Epson M244A** for print ticket in the store, but i don't know how to configurate the sheet size(width and heigth), for one a multiples objects for each product sell.

[image: Image example]

For example, how to do, when have one item (Ticket 1) and multiples item's (Ticket 2).

Answer (score 0):

The ticket output is based on an Access report? I expect the report will have to be a report/subreport design with textboxes and labels on the subreport arranged vertically.

This presumes conventional normalized data structure with a parent table for the order header info and a related dependent table with products ordered details.

Comment: Yes, but i try with a macro to print but happened this, [link image](http://imgur.com/a/MNRwS). I want that, **Paga 1 of 1**, is in auto height, and not in format acces for default.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand that. What do you mean by 'in auto height' and 'not in format access for default'.

Comment: I want the printed ticket to be adapted to the length of the customer's purchase to the order quantity, and not as it is in the image that I put in the previous comment, which as you can see, only two articles, but there is still a space in White of the generated report.

Comment: You want to eliminate white space between records and page footer so the page number prints just under the last record? This is an issue I have never seen a solution for.

Comment: Thanks for all, i try to use the configure when install driver for that ticket printer